# Referring to x data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to access the x and y data of ggplot?

```
data.frame(U = 1:8, V = 2:9) %>%

  # Use the potentially unknown column names
  ggplot(aes(x = !!rlang::sym(colnames(.)[[1]]), y = !!rlang::sym(colnames(.)[[2]]))) +

  # But instead of e.g.
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(X)), data = ~(data.frame(X = .x[[1]]))) +

  # want something like this:
  #geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(..x..))) +  

  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are changing the data for `geom_vline()`. You can refer to the variable the same way you did in the global `aes()` (though you need to not pipe the dataframe into ggplot and instead refer to it directly).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(ggplot2)
df <- cars
varnames <- colnames(df) %>% setNames(c("x", "y"))
ggplot(df) +
    aes(x = !!sym(colnames(df)[1]), y = !!sym(colnames(df)[2])) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(!!sym(colnames(df)[1]))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Another approach if you really want to pipe might be to rename the columns of the dataframe and then put those names back into the plot later with `scale_*()` functions:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
df <- cars
varnames <- colnames(df) %>% setNames(c("x", "y"))
df %>%
  setNames(c("x", "y")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(x))) +
  scale_x_continuous(varnames["x"]) +
  scale_y_continuous(varnames["y"])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This isn't dry enough; case in point: your typo in `y = !!sym(colnames(df)[1])`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the `!!sym(colnames(...))` construct isn't something I would generally recommend. Just following your lead. The second example is quite DRY.